# What is the best way to optimize clearcase dynamic view performance on a linux client?

Tags: linux, performance

```
 cleartool getcache -view -cview           


Lookup cache:    94% full,   6080 entries (307.0K), 308777 requests,  86% hits
Readdir cache:   77% full,   4534 entries (1259.4K),  52233 requests,  91% hits
Fstat cache:     89% full,   6188 entries (870.2K), 137811 requests, 100% hits
Object cache:   100% full,   6188 entries (1146.9K), 290977 requests,  42% hits
Total memory used for view caches: 3583.5Kbytes
The current view server cache limits are:
Lookup cache:             335520 bytes
Readdir cache:           1677721 bytes
Fstat cache:             1006560 bytes
Object cache:            1174320 bytes
Total cache size limit:  4194304 bytes

Should I try to get my Object cache hit to be 100%?

I have 2GB RAM.
```

Answer (score 1):

A hit in the cache means that when the lookup was performed, it was found in the cache.
The statistic only shows how much you saved without having to make a round-trip query to the server.